# Return list of objects within abject's attribute when many equals True, in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

In DRF, how can I return a list of objects inside an array within an object's attribute, instead of a direct array.

Let's say I execute the following code:

```
people = Person.objects.all()
serializer = PersonSerializer(people, many=True)
print(serializer.data)
```

The output would be something the following:

```
[{'name': 'John'}, {'name': 'Rebbeca'}]
```

However, I would like it to be:

```
{'people': [{'name': 'John'}, {'name': 'Rebbeca'}]}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply do:

```
people = Person.objects.all()
serializer = PersonSerializer(people, many=True)
serializer.data = {'people': serializer.data}
print(serializer.data)
```

Comment: I wonder if there's not a most elegant way. Like doing it inside the serializer itself.